# disable all animations to a div or html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have an animation that flashes whenever i add an item to a div, I am not sure if its a jquery animation? its like a flash/blink that refreshes the div and adds data to the div.

is there a way to disable all the animations that are being applied to the div?

```
 * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
}

jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

This is what i have tried but it did not seem to work

I am using a library that is just put inside the div, so i am not sure what adds the animation

Answer (score 0):

AS you want to be sure its none of child, patent, pseudo-elements, you can use

```
* { -webkit-transition: none !important; -moz-transition: none !important; -o-transition: none !important; transition: none !important; }
```

Comment: Sorry! it's what ive tried but ive cut it out by accident

Comment: Then it is probably done by javascript. post a link to the page you need help with

Comment: It's actually a library called 'js-year-calendar' whenever you add dates to the calendar it has an effect added